# Jumping back outside of a switch statement

Tags: php

I am wondering how to jump back outside a switch statement if a certain case is met, as the code will have to retry what it has just done. Here an example of my code;

```
$result = $this->check($user, $password); 

switch($result){
    case 'invalid-email-password':
        //Do stuff
        break;

    case 'error':
        //Do stuff
        //Jump back to $result = $this->check to try again
        break;
```

The code should only continue when the 'error' case is no longer the result of the `$this->check()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to program a "retry until it works" thing, consider this:

```
while(true) {
    doSomething();

    if( $it_worked) break;
}
```

Note that since you're in a `switch` statement, you will need to use `break 2;` on a successful result to exit out of both the `switch` and the `while`.

To prevent an infinite loop, you can have an `$attempts` counter that counts down and breaks the loop manually if you run out of tries.

Comment: What happens to my `break` in the `switch` statement? Shall I leave them in there, or only `break 2` on a valid result?